# pykakasiで文字列置き換えの際にKeyErrorが発生する

Tags: python, python3, pykakasi

pykakasiを用いて、漢字をひらがなに置き換えをしようとしています。
また、この文字列には、特殊な文字が一部含まれています。

Python3.6ではこのままでも問題がなかったのですが、
Python3.7ではKeyErrorとして止まってしまうようになりました。

3.7の場合はどのような対応をすれば良いでしょうか？

記述事例としては以下となります。

```py
def text_convert():

    text = "文字列置き換え"

    from pykakasi import kakasi
    kakasi = kakasi()
    kakasi.setMode("J", "H")
    convert = kakasi.getConverter()

    text = convert.do(text)
    print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_convert()
```

エラーとしては以下の内容です。

```py
KeyError: b'e098'
```

ご教示いただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: 手元で再現出来ましたので、Pykakasi側のバグのように見えます。リポジトリ側にIssueを立てておきました。 [KeyError with specific character · Issue #68 · miurahr/pykakasi](https://github.com/miurahr/pykakasi/issues/68)

Comment: すみません、コメント見落としてました。
ご確認とバグ報告対応ありがとうございます。
対応されることを気長に待ちたいと思います！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントしたように [KeyError with specific character · Issue #68 · miurahr/pykakasi](https://github.com/miurahr/pykakasi/issues/68) というIssueを作成し、一旦推移を見守っておりましたが、2019年6月6日にこれを修正するコミットが行われ、先述のIssueはクローズされました。

[Fix #68 · miurahr/pykakasi@3d92897](https://github.com/miurahr/pykakasi/commit/3d928973311c8fefbf585aa08c06b3e702052645)

という訳で、最新版（下記のv0.95）で確認したところ、無事記載されたコードは正しく動きました。

[Release v0.95: README: fix azure-pipelines badge · miurahr/pykakasi](https://github.com/miurahr/pykakasi/releases/tag/v0.95)

という訳で、本質問に対する回答としては**v0.95以上にアップデートする**となります。